How to change Ag-grid react sidebar searchbox placeholder?
I'm using ag-grid-react 31.1.1 with React 18.2.
I want to change placeholder of sidebar search box.

This is my DefaultSideBar Props:
export const defaultSidebarDef = {
  toolPanels: [
    {
      id: 'columns',
      labelDefault: 'Columns'
      labelKey: 'columns',
      iconKey: 'columns',
      toolPanel: 'agColumnsToolPanel',
      minWidth: 180,
      maxWidth: 400,
      width: 250,
      toolPanelParams: {
        suppressRowGroups: true,
        suppressValues: true,
        suppressPivotMode: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  position: 'right',
  defaultToolPanel: '',
};


Here is the My AgGridReact component. I'm importing AgGridReact from 'ag-grid-react' package.
      <AgGridReact
        ref={gridRef}
        getRowId={getRowId}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
        sideBar={defaultSidebarDef}
        rowSelection={'multiple'}
        suppressRowClickSelection={true}
        rowModelType={'serverSide'}
        cacheBlockSize={SEARCH_SERVICE_CONFIGS.LIMIT_DEFAULT}
        onGridReady={onGridReady}
        onModelUpdated={(event) => onModelUpdated(event, gridViewStateManager)}
        statusBar={statusBar}
        suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns
        noRowsOverlayComponent={NoRowsOverlay}
        noRowsOverlayComponentParams={noRowsOverlayComponentParams}
        suppressContextMenu={true}
        suppressBrowserResizeObserver={true}
        onSortChanged={onSortChanged}
        context={{
          t,
          tool: {
            id: tool,
          },
          projectCountry,
        }}
      />


Please show your code

I added an answer

You can use the localeText object :
<AgGridReact
        ref={gridRef}
        getRowId={getRowId}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        localeText={{
           searchOoo: 'Your custom placeholder',
        }}
      />


Is it possible to handle onchange or onclick of seach box?

You might be able to add events listeners manually yes.
